# Tensorflow reshape with variable length

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the following reshape in my model:

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (BATCH_SIZE, N_CHUNK, WIN * N_SENSOR))

data_flattened = tf.reshape(data, [BATCH_SIZE*N_CHUNK, WIN*N_SENSOR])
```

Now I want N_CHUNK to be variable (i.e. NONE in the dimension). How do I implement the reshape? Does the None dimension must be the first dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.shape` to get a shape as an integer Tensor.

So in your example:

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (BATCH_SIZE, None, WIN * N_SENSOR))

data_flattened = tf.reshape(data, [BATCH_SIZE*tf.shape(data)[1], WIN*N_SENSOR])
```